# Getting 500 error when loading document page next.js vercel app after second load

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, http-status-code-500

I have a next.js app hosted on vercel which keeps giving me a 500 error when trying to load one of my pages. From chrome dev tools I can see the error is originating when it tries to request the document page `/dashboard`. I know it's not a server error as my backend works fine in development and when using postman (locally and with the production api url). It just loads a blank page when the request returns a 500 error.

Something else which is strange: when you first load the page after clearing cache/just logging out, it'll load perfectly fine. However after the first refresh it returns a 500 error when trying to access the `dashboard` page.

When the 500 error is thrown, I can see from the network tab in dev tools that it isn't even getting to the point of sending requests to my backend.

The production url is [here](https://earmark-alpha.vercel.app)

Use the login credentials
`test@email.com`
`Test_user1234!`

After it should automatically route you to the `/dashboard` page, and it should load on the first request (be patient, first load is very slow). Then if you try and reload it'll throw the 500 error.

The requested data will be cached in localstorage.

Comment: A 500 error is a server exception.

Comment: I understand that, I just don't understand what's causing it. It's not my backend because the error is thrown before any requests are made to the backend. It also works fine locally so that's another point of confusion.

Comment: Well it's coming from *some* backend. The developer tab should show you the URL involved.

Comment: The request is being made to my webpage url (https://earmark-alpha.vercel.app/dashboard), so I'm guessing that means it's an error on the vercel side since it's hosted on the vercel webpage hosting platform

Comment: That would make sense. I don't know anything about what sorts of server-side diagnostics are available there, but that's where I'd start looking.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your db connected or not, make sure to make a global function for connection which connects to db automatically if db connection stops.